# Measuring time of Quick and Heap sort in python

Tags: python, quicksort, heapsort

I'm measuring time of Quick and Heap sort in Python, but the diffrence between results is too big. Please take a moment to look at my code:

```
import time
import linecache
import random

def shell_sort(some_list):
    h=1
    while(h<=len(some_list)):
        h=3*h+1
    while h>0:
        for i in xrange(len(some_list)):
            j = i
            temp = some_list[i]
            while j >= h and some_list[j-h] > temp:
                some_list[j] = some_list[j - h]
                j -= h
            some_list[j] = temp
        h = h/3 if h/9 else (0 if h==1 else 1)
    some_list.reverse()

def quick_sort_r(some_list):
    l = []
    e = []
    g = []
    if len(some_list) <= 1:
        return some_list
    else:
        pivot = some_list[0]
        for x in some_list:
            if x < pivot:
                l.append(x)
            elif x > pivot:
                g.append(x)
            else:
                e.append(x)
        l = quick_sort_r(l)
        g = quick_sort_r(g)
        return g + e + l

def gen(number, b=100000):
    #return [random.randint(0, b) for x in xrange(number)]
    some_list = []
    return [some_list.append(random.randint(0, b)) for x in xrange(number)]

domain = [10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000]
for element in domain:
    print 'Results for: ' + str(element) + ' elements:'
    for j in range(0, 10):
        temp_list = gen(element)
        start = time.time()
        shell_sort(temp_list)
        end = time.time() - start
        print end
    print '*************************'
```

I'm using two types of code in function 'gen'. First works with heap sort and the second with quick sort. Hopefully there is too big difference and this cannot be correct. QS for 1000000 elements is about 0.5 s and HS is 23 s. What's wrong?

Thanks from advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't know what you are asking. Why is this difference too big? Note that I would compare the sort time on the same datasets, randomly generated. Different sort algorithms perform differently depending on how sorted the data is already. So sending 2 different inputs to each algorithm is probably not the best test. Creating a single dataset to test with using random numbers, and pass that same set to both algorithms.

Comment: You're right, but even when I'm sorting sorted list the problem appears. I start being confused when I realized that complexity of Quicksort for sorted ascending, sorted descending and not sorted (random) is the same. It's of course mistake, because pessimistic complexity is O(n^2) and optimistic is O(n*logn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
return [some_list.append(random.randint(0, b)) for x in xrange(number)]
```

... is a list comprehension that generates the result of `number` calls to `some_list.append(...)`, all of which return `None`:

```
>>> print gen(10)
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

`None`s compare like this:

```
>>> None < None
False
>>> None > None
False
```

So I would imagine both of your sorts are rather confused.

The quicksort is faster because with a list of `None`s, it becomes a function that copies a list:

```
def quick_sort_r(some_list):
    e = []
    if len(some_list) <= 1:
        return some_list
    else:
        pivot = some_list[0]
        for x in some_list:
            # all other comparisons are False
            e.append(x)

        return e
```

In summary, use `return [random.randint(0, b) for x in xrange(number)]` instead. On my machine, that change takes the quicksort from 0.43s to 8.9s, which is probably more what you were expecting.

Incidentally, unless you have a fast machine, Python isn't going to agree with a list of 1,000,000 numbers very well - it takes my (somewhat slow) computer about 3 seconds to generate a list of 1 million numbers.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Did you use my code for QS? It isn't working with this 'return [random.randint(0, b) for x in xrange(number)]'. Even when I'm trying to sort list of 10000 elements.

Comment: Okay, it's working on 10000 elements but only when they are random. When I try to sort list of 10000 sorted elements it's error with recursion depth.